# css switch div positions on resize

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have some divs repositioned based upon the window size, using @media declarations.  I can get the first switches to work, except for the large space between container 1 and 2.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container1">
        <div id="a">
            A Element
        </div>
        <div id="b">
            B Element
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div id="c">
            C Element
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            D Element
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle code for it:
https://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/w1frhwub/1/

I am trying to get the last @media to go to this layout but keep the div element contents the same.  I.E. reposition the divs/resize them.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container1">
        <div id="a">
            A Element
        </div>
        <div id="c">
            C Element
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div id="b">
            B Element
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            D Element
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE for it:
https://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/w1frhwub/3/

[be sure to switch your window widths to see the differences]

Is there a way with flex or a :before :after to make this happen on a resize?

Note:  I don't want to use any jQuery, only CSS3 and HTML5.

{sorry, didn't show it well, without people going to JSFiddle initially.}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way. Using flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -moz-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container1,
.container2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.container1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.container2 {
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width: 560px) {
  .container2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  .container1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container1">
        <div id="a">
            A Element
        </div>
        <div id="b">
            B Element
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div id="c">
            C Element
        </div>
        <div id="d">
            D Element
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This almost works.  I thought I could use order, and it does work to switch just two of the containers, but if you look closer at the code, it is switching the divs between the two containers, i.e. container 1 has A and B, container 2 has C and D, once it gets bigger, container 1 has A and "C", **not** B", and container 2 has B and D, **not** "C".  Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I know, it was just helping you forward. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out a solution.  It's using sort of double duty, but it works.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="containerA">
    <div class="container1A">
      <div id="a">
        A Element
      </div>
      <div id="b">
        B Element
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2A">
      <div id="c">
        C Element
      </div>
      <div id="d">
        D Element
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="containerB">
    <div class="container1B">
      <div id="a">
        A Element
      </div>
      <div id="c">
        C Element
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2B">
      <div id="b">
        B Element
      </div>
      <div id="d">
        D Element
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.containerA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.containerB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#a {
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#c {
  background-color: green;
}
#d {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .containerA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .containerB {
    display: none;
  }
  .container1A {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .container2A {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .container1B{
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
  }
  .container2B {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
  }
  #a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  #b {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  #c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  #d {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  .containerA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .containerB {
    display: none;
  }
  .container1A {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .container2A {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .container1B {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
  }
  .container2B {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
  }
  #a {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  #b {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
  }
  #c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  #d {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .containerA {
    display: none;
  }

  .containerB {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .container1A {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
  }
  .container2A {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
  }
  .container1B {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  .container2B {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
  }
  #a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 66%;
  }
  #b {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
  }
  #c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
  }
  #d {
    width: 100%;
    height: 66%;
  }
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/trout0525/w1frhwub/5/